# pytest - Change variable values in cells of Jupyter notebooks during execution

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytest

We are planning to add an integration test to our Jupyter notebooks to verify that they run end-to-end by using `pytest` and the `nbval` plugin.
One feature that we would like to have is the ability to parametarize notebook executions, so that we can try different values for variables in the Jupyter notebook cells and effectively test multiple scenarios for the same notebook.

E.g.

```
foo = 1
```

```
print(foo)
```

We would like to be able to assign any value like 1,2,3,100,900, etc to foo and see the output of execution. Essentially something like:
`<EXECUTE_NOTEBOOK> -p foo=2`
`<EXECUTE_NOTEBOOK> -p foo=3`
`<EXECUTE_NOTEBOOK> -p foo=4`
`<EXECUTE_NOTEBOOK> -p foo=100`
`<EXECUTE_NOTEBOOK> -p foo=900`

and see the different outputs.

We know that papermill already supports something like this: https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-execute.html#execute-via-the-python-api

Does pytest have a feature like this as well?

Answer (score 2):

You could go with Papermill as one option, however you could also try parametrizing your tests inside the notebook itself, to avoid running each param set as a separate test (as in the example above). One way to do this is with the [ipytest](https://github.com/chmp/ipytest) library, which is similar to `nbval`, but in my opinion a bit more straightforward ([here is the example notebook](https://github.com/chmp/ipytest/blob/master/Example.ipynb)).

If you basically have *one input value* that you want to manipulate and that will then determine the output of the whole notebook, one idea for what you could do is:

1. wrap all the other functions/steps in the notebook into one function in the end
2. use cell magic `%%run_pytest[clean]` so that `ipython` knows to run this cell
3. decorate it with `@pytest.mark.parametrize` to pass the values you want to test

This way your whole notebook will be rerun a few times based on the params passed to this function.

Comment: Hi @tania, the idea is to run the notebooks E2E, to verify that there will be no issues in their execution and make sure they run successfully. As such, it won't be simple to refactor every line of code into a set of functions which can then be unit-tested. I thought of doing that, but quickly ran into issues, so its a no go. This is also the main reason that we prefer `nbval` as it helps in running the notebook from top to the bottom and reports on any exceptions or errors that are encountered. Sadly, it doesn't let us paramterize.

Comment: I see, thanks getting back to me  then most likely papermill is the way to go. Also, check our `nbsmoke` if all you need is to check that the notebook still runs with no errors raised. `nbval` and the like look for equality of output, which might be harder to guarantee.